# How to get system classification rules defined in the Azure purview account using a http call

Tags: azure, classification, azure-purview

I'm trying to get all the classification rules (system and custom) enabled in the azure purview account using below http call
GET {Endpoint}/classificationrules?api-version=2018-12-01-preview

But, I'm getting only the custom classification rules defined in the account as the response.
But, there are list of system classification rules are enabled in that particular ifs purview account.

According to the documentation, I should get the system classification rules as the response

Could you please tell what I need to do for getting system classification rules in the response

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/scanningdataplane/classification-rules/list-all

Comment: Does someone know about this

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, there is no way to get system classification rules defined in the Azure purview account using a http call.

As per the confirmation from products team that the API returns only Custom Scan Classifications rules and System classifications are not returned to reduce the size of the payload as it is documented properly [list of all supported system classifications.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/supported-classifications)

Please provide your feedback at [Azure Purview Feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/82d7bddb-fb24-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8) channel so that community can upvote and products team can plan to include in their future release.